# Why does this reddit code max out the CPU?

Tags: javascript

I found this on reddit, but I do not understand exactly why the code is bad. I read that it maxes out the CPU, but I do not see any infinite loop going on, since i is always being incremented and it is checked whether or not it is smaller than 10.

```
var data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
var opacity;

for(var i=0; i<data.length && i<10; i++){
  opacity = .5;
  if(i=0)
    opacity = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` variable keeps reseting to `0` because of the use of only one `=` sign, thus, instead of comparing, it's setting the value:

```
if( i = 0 )
   // ^ Missing = in order to perform comparison.
```

Answer (score 3):

Look closely at what is happening in `if(i=0)` .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @IswantoSan This answer uses the educational method illustrated here: https://xkcd.com/1028/